# VBA = Applying Dynamic values to Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA scripting. Though I could successfully write a simple code using `Do...While` to update multiple rows in same column, I am unable to apply the logic across various ranges of Rows / Columns.

Could you please tell how to optimize the script which will perform the same operation across various cells

```
Dim I as Integer, Start as Integer
I = 5

Do while I < 250
    Start = Cells(I, 11).value * Cells (I,12).value

    If Cells (I,8).value = "Professional services" then
        Cells (I,52).value = Start * 1.13
    Else
        Cells (I, 52).value = Start
    End if

    I = I + 1
Loop
```

Note: I want to call the Cell "52" across various columns (eg: 52, 53, 54 etc)

Comment: Use the Excel GUI to do this and have the macro recorder running while you do so. Then review the code it wrote for you.

Comment: `.offset` will also be a good place to start.